# Unable to get MainWindowTitle of Spotify process

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to develop a program that will read the MainWindowTitle of music programs (found by ProcessName) in order to identify the song that is currently playing.  However, Spotify is being particularly troublesome as I can clearly see the ProcessName for Spotify is "Spotify".

I am able to put the Spotify ProcessName and MainWindowTitle into a listbox (and the process name shows as "Spotify" and I can see the currently playing song as the MainWindowTitle) using the following code:

```
    Dim procList() As Process = Process.GetProcesses()
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    For Each P As Process In procList
        Dim strProcName As String = P.ProcessName
        If P.MainWindowTitle <> "" Then
            If P.MainWindowTitle <> Me.Text Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add(P.MainWindowTitle & "|" & P.ProcessName)
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

I am also able to get the currently playing song on MusicBee using the below code:

```
    'Identify Currently playing song
    Dim procList() As Process = Process.GetProcesses()
    For Each P As Process In procList
        Dim strProcName As String = P.ProcessName
        If P.ProcessName = "MusicBee" Then
            LabelNowPlaying.Text = P.MainWindowTitle
        End If
    Next
```

However, I am unable to set a label as the MainWindowTitle of Spotify using the below code:

```
    'Identify Currently playing song
    Dim procList() As Process = Process.GetProcesses()
    For Each P As Process In procList
        Dim strProcName As String = P.ProcessName
        If P.ProcessName = "Spotify" Then
            LabelNowPlaying.Text = P.MainWindowTitle
        End If
    Next
```

How can I get Spotify's MainWindowTitle by ProcessName?  How is it possible that "Spotify" isn't working for the ProcessName when the same code told me it was?

Comment: Have you actually debugged the code properly, i.e. with breakpoints and stepping through it?  My first guess would be that there are multiple processes with that name and the last one has a blank `MainWindowTitle`.  Your first code snippet would not show you that process while you last code snippet would replace the value from the first process with the blank value from the last one.  ALWAYS debug your code.  Even if I'm wrong, at least you will see clearly that I'm wrong and not have to guess.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't nest `If` blocks like that.  Only nest `If` blocks if you need to.  In that first code snippet, you only need one `If` block: `If P.MainWindowTitle <> "" AndAlso P.MainWindowTitle <> Me.Text Then`.

Comment: Pretty likely that this is a UWP app, in other words came from the Windows Store.  Such programs march to a very different drummer, the main window is provided by the operating system and the app's window is a child of that window.  Only practical way to get ahead is to use UI Automation, System.Windows.Automation namespace in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you say works and doesn't, I would think that this would get you what you need:

```
LabelNowPlaying.Text = Process.GetProcessesByName("Spotify").
                               FirstOrDefault(Function(p) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle))?.
                               MainWindowTitle
```

That will get an array of all and just the Spotify processes and then display the main window title of the first one that has one or a blank if there are none.

Note specifically the null propagation operator before `MainWindowTitle`, i.e. `?.` rather than just `.`.  That will invoke the specified member if there is an object to invoke it on, or the expression terminates there and evaluates to `Nothing`.

If you wanted to expand that out:

```
Dim spotifyProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("Spotify")
Dim spotifyWindowProcesses = spotifyProcesses.Where(Function(p) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle))
Dim firstSpotifyWindowProcess = spotifyWindowProcesses.FirstOrDefault()

If firstSpotifyWindowProcess Is Nothing Then
    LabelNowPlaying.Text = Nothing
Else
    LabelNowPlaying.Text = firstSpotifyWindowProcess.MainWindowTitle
End If
```

Using your original logic:

```
Dim spotifyProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("Spotify")

For Each p In spotifyProcesses
    Dim mainWindowTitle = p.MainWindowTitle

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(mainWindowTitle) Then
        LabelNowPlaying.Text = mainWindowTitle
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Note the use of `Exit For` to stop looking when a match is found.  Even if this code can't overwrite the first value with another empty value, it could still keep looking pointlessly for a value when it already has one.  If you achieve your aim in a loop, stop looping.  That's exactly what methods like `FirstOrDefault` do internally.